# Can I create a stright line having circle at both ends with Clip path CSS?

Tags: css, clip-path

I will like to achieve something like this

[image]

I have tried using clip path, but I am struggling achieving the desired result. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you show us the code for what you've tried? Did you intend for the border of the circles to be noticeable or did you want the entire thing to flow as one shape?

Comment: @AStombaugh I want the entire thing to be one shape. Here is a rough sketch of it https://codepen.io/deluxscript/pen/yLvEKMW, but it is not working the way I would love it to

Answer (score 2):

You need mask for this:

```css
.box {
  --h: 50px;  /* height of the element */
  --b: 60%;   /* height of the bar */
  width: 200px;
  
  height: var(--h);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,red, blue);
  -webkit-mask: 
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) 
      50%/calc(100% - var(--h)) var(--b) no-repeat, 
    radial-gradient(calc(var(--h)/2) at calc(var(--h)/2) 50%, #000 96%, #0000) 
      0 50%/calc(100% - var(--h)) 100% repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="width:300px;--b:45%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, you'd probably be better off using an SVG (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) instead of a clip-path if you need something like that. Here's one I did really quickly in Illustrator but you can make SVGs in several other apps as well. Not saying you necessarily *couldn't* use a clip-path to accomplish this but it seems like it would be more work than the 5 minutes it took to make the SVG and map the gradient.

```css
svg {
  fill: url(#gradient);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 500 250">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ff77" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ffef00" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M350.333,84.055c-15.52,0-28.956,8.881-35.531,21.833H105.531C98.957,92.937,85.52,84.055,70,84.055
    c-22,0-39.833,17.834-39.833,39.833c0,22,17.834,39.834,39.833,39.834c15.52,0,28.956-8.881,35.531-21.833h209.271
    c6.574,12.952,20.011,21.833,35.53,21.833c21.999,0,39.833-17.834,39.833-39.834C390.166,101.889,372.332,84.055,350.333,84.055z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, hopefully I would be able to use this to create more connecting circles, that is possible with the svg method right? I am new to this css property 

Comment: Yeah, this was just for demo purposes. You can make whatever shape you want and export the path. Someone also posted a method using masks so you could use that too